# HTTP status code 403 received when trying to retrieve response from GetAsync

Tags: c#, rest, api, oauth

I am trying to get some information from an API using `GetAsync`, but I am getting a status code of 403 even after adding the OAuth authorization header with the token provided for me. Is there something else I need to do, or is my token bad?

```
class TestAPI
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_ADDRESS_FOR_TESTING);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("OAuth", TOKEN);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("WebApi/CaseLogs/v10/Search?DateFrom=04-05-2012");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine((int) response.StatusCode); // prints "403"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HttpClient looks fine to me. I think your Token is bad.

The 403 Error also supports this theory.

> 403 
>   FORBIDDEN The server understood the
>   request but refuses to authorize it.
>
> A server that wishes to make public why the request has been forbidden
>   can describe that reason in the response payload (if any).
>   https://httpstatuses.com/403

You should also print your response message.

```
        using ( HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("WebApi/CaseLogs/v10/Search?DateFrom=04-05-2012"))
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {            
            string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

Try this code to see if you get more information in the response content.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's what I thought, I just wanted to verify.